# Arrange posts by date in front page

Tags: categories, order, date, frontpage

I have code to show the 5 last posts from every category on the front page. However, at the moment they are ordered category by category. Is it possible to order them by post date, but still have 5 posts per category?

Here is my current code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if( $cats = get_categories() ) foreach( $cats as $cat ) :
//go through all site's categories and get up to 5 posts each////

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
        'category__in' => array($cat->term_id),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged
        ) );

        if($cat_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<h3 class="cat-title"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h3>
        <?php while ($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );

        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `orderby` and `order` to your arguments:

```
$cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'category__in' => array($cat->term_id),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
) );
```

**Update**

> it seems it still takes one category, lists 5 posts and then goes to another, with 5 posts etc. It takes the last posts, but they are listid one category after anoter

Try this instead then:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$i = 0;

if ( $cats = get_categories() ) foreach( $cats as $cat ) :
    $cat_query = new WP_Query( 
        array(
            'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'category__in' => array ( $cat->term_id ),
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
            // arrays of all the posts' IDs and dates
            $the_posts['ID'][$i] = $post->ID;
            $the_posts['date'][$i] = $post->post_date;

            $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;

foreach ( $the_posts['date'] as $the_post_date ) {
    $post_dates[] = $the_post_date;
}

// sort all the posts by their dates
array_multisort( $post_dates, SORT_DESC, $the_posts['ID'] );

foreach ( $the_posts['ID'] as $the_post_id ) {
    $post_ids[] = $the_post_id;
}

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $post_ids ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <h3 class="cat-title"><?php $cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() ); echo $cat[0]->name; ?></h3>
    <?php
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
    endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but it seems it still takes one category, lists 5 posts and then goes to another, with 5 posts etc. It takes the last posts, but they are listid one category after anoter.

Comment: @risto - I've updated my post.